# Difference between now() and current_timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

In PostgreSQL, I use the `now()` and `current_timestamp` function and I see no difference:

```
# SELECT now(), current_timestamp;
              now               |              now               
--------------------------------+--------------------------------
 04/20/2014 19:44:27.215557 EDT | 04/20/2014 19:44:27.215557 EDT
(1 row)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

There is **no difference**. [Three quotes from the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

1.:

> These SQL-standard functions all return values based on the start time
> of the current transaction:
> ...
> **`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`**
> ...

2.:

> **`transaction_timestamp()`** is equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but is
> named to clearly reflect what it returns.

3.:

> **`now()`** is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to `transaction_timestamp()`.

**Bold** emphasis mine. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `transaction_timestamp()` and `now()` do *exactly* the same. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a syntactical oddity for a function, having no trailing pair of parentheses. That's according to the SQL standard.

If you don't declare a column alias for a function call in an SQL statement, the alias defaults to the name of the function. Internally, the standard-SQL `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is implemented with `now()`. Up to Postgres 9.6 that shows in the resulting **column name**, which was "now", but changed to "current_timestamp" in Postgres 10.

`transaction_timestamp()` does the same, but this one is a proper Postgres function, so the default alias has always been "transaction_timestamp".

Do **not** confuse either of these *functions* with the special [date/time input constant `'now'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE). That's just one of several notational shorthands for specific date/time/timestamp values, [quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#idm46428712638688)

> ...  that will be converted to ordinary date/time values when read. (In particular, `now` and related strings are converted to a specific time value as soon as they are read.) All of these values need to be enclosed in single quotes when used as constants in SQL commands.

It may add to the confusion that (up to at least Postgres 16) any number of leading and trailing spaces and brackets (`{[( )]}`) are trimmed from those special input values. So `'now()'::timestamptz` - or just `'now()'` without explicit type cast where the data type can be derived from context, or even `' {)[ now  () []  '` - is also valid and happens to evaluate to the same timestamp as the function `now()` *in most contexts*. But those are *constants* and typically *not* what you want as column default for instance.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f7956cced731a2fe35be1b61873e2a45)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/9098)</sub>

Notable alternatives are **`statement_timestamp()`** and **`clock_timestamp()`**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

> `statement_timestamp()` returns the start time of the current
> statement (more specifically, the time of receipt of the latest
> command message from the client). [...]
> `clock_timestamp()` returns the actual current time, and therefore its
> value changes even within a single SQL command.

Note: `statement_timestamp()` is **`STABLE`** just like all variants of `now()`. (They always return the same value within the same SQL command). But `clock_timestamp()` necessarily is only `VOLATILE`. The difference may be significant.

Comment: but, does it make a difference for query optimization? will now() be executed for every row in: `where items.createddate > now()` ?

Comment: @santiagoarizti: No. `now()` is defined `STABLE` because it evaluates to the same value (the start time of the current transaction) within the same transaction. I your example, `now()` is executed *once* only (as opposed to [`clock_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) for instance).

Answer (score 1):

In addition that they have no functional difference when you use them properly, they are casted differently:

`'now()'` recongnized (just like `'today'` or `'now'`):

```
b=# select 'now()'::timestamptz;
          timestamptz
-------------------------------
 2016-12-09 16:31:35.942243+00
(1 row)
```

`'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` gives [funny error from dark edges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/datatype-datetime.html)

> Note: As of PostgreSQL version 7.2, 'current' is no longer supported
>   as a date/time constant

```
b=# select 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'::timestamptz;
ERROR:  date/time value "current" is no longer supported
LINE 1: select 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'::timestamptz;
               ^
```

and `'transaction_timestamp()'` is just not recongized as timestamp with tz value:

```
b=# select 'transaction_timestamp()'::timestamptz;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "transaction_timestamp()"
LINE 1: select 'transaction_timestamp()'::timestamptz;
               ^
```

Please don't ask why would you cast `'now()' as timestamp`. I've seen `where timestamp_column = 'now()'` instead of `where timestamp_column = now()` in people code, so thought this clarification would be funny fact and good addition to Erwin's answer.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding. The [input string `'now()'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE) looks similar to the function `now()` on the surface, but is not directly related otherwise. `'now'` is a constant evaluating to the *current transaction's start time*. Trailing parens are ignored. The attempt to cast the strings `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` or `'transaction_timestamp()'` to `timestamp` in similar fashion fails, because that's just nonsense. Neither is related to the corresponding functions.

Comment: This answer is confusing opposed to the other answer, especially with the quotes.