# ALTER timestamptz column to timestamp without "converting" data?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, timezone

It seems that altering a column from `timestamp without time zone` to `timestamp with time zone` converts the existing data based on the current session time zone at the time of the `alter` statement.

See this example, output shown after each statement

```
create table tztest (col1 timestamp without time zone);

set timezone = 'UTC';
insert into tztest (col1) values ('2023-02-01 10:10:10');
select col1 as t1, extract(epoch FROM col1) from tztest;
-- → 2023-02-01 10:10:10    1675246210

set timezone = 'America/New_York';
alter table tztest alter column col1 type timestamp with time zone;
select col1 as t2, extract(epoch FROM col1) from tztest;
-- → 2023-02-01 10:10:10-05 1675264210

set timezone = 'UTC';
select col1 as t3, extract(epoch FROM col1) from tztest;
-- → 2023-02-01 15:10:10+00 1675264210
```

The epoch value changes after the `alter` command.
I was expecting that PG would assume the `timestamp` value was UTC and not adjust it when changing the type to `timestamp with time zone` (giving me `t2` of `05:10:10` and `t3` of `10:10:10`).

However, it seems PG assumes the session time zone at the time of the `alter`, and converts them to UTC.

Is my understanding correct, and is it expected behavior?

On a large table then the alter will update every row, which is something we are concerned about and certainly want to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Don't rely on the fallback (the timezone setting of the current session) without setting it yourself explicitly.
If your timestamps shall be interpreted as UTC timestamps, be explicit about it. It's best to set the session `timezone` for this particular case and run `ALTER TABLE` with the simple [`SET DATA TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html). Only this case can take the shortcut without table rewrite (see below):

```
SET timezone = 'UTC';
ALTER TABLE tztest ALTER COLUMN col1 TYPE timestamptz;
```

You can also apply [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) in a `USING` clause to [`SET DATA TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE tztest ALTER COLUMN col1 TYPE timestamptz
USING col1 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

The epoch value stays the same either way, because Postgres stores `timestamptz` as UTC timestamps internally. Postgres has to rebuild any index involving `col1` in any case.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gyp_i8DX)

See:

- [Convert Postgres TIMESTAMP to TIMESTAMPTZ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134385/convert-postgres-timestamp-to-timestamptz/134603#134603)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

#### Table rewrite?

> On a large table then the alter will update every row ...

Except for noted exceptions, `ALTER TABLE` rewrites the whole table and all indexes (taking an exclusive lock for the duration!). Changing the type to a binary coercible type (like `text` --> `varchar`) can avoid it. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-NOTES)

> As an exception, when changing the type of an existing column, if the `USING` clause does not change the column contents and the old type is either binary coercible to the new type or an unconstrained domain over the new type, a table rewrite is not needed.

Postgres does not realize this for the expression with `AT TIME ZONE`.
**But** - like Jeff commented - the simple `SET DATA TYPE` with the session time zone set to UTC qualifies. The [release notes for **Postgres 12**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.19.5.3.5):

> Allow `ALTER TABLE ... SET DATA TYPE` changing between `timestamp` and
> `timestamptz` to avoid a table rewrite when the session time zone is
> UTC (Noah Misch)
>
> In the UTC time zone, these two data types are binary compatible.

Older versions were not as smart. Compare:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OSLGk2mQ) -- Postgres 11
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yZX_xDX1) -- Postgres 12

Also note that a rewrite is not an `UPDATE`, which produces dead tuples and bloats the table, but does not interfere with concurrent reads with its weaker lock. This completely rewrites the whole table in pristine condition, but takes an exclusive lock for the duration.

Related:

- [Will changing column from timestamp to timestamptz lock the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481513/939860)

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. We are using AWS DMS to convert from IBM DB2 into PG. The DB2 data is in ET. We can't control the DMS connection time zone (it sets to UTC). So the only manner we have fond to get this to work is to rely on ALTER to convert the data. But at our scale I am not sure the ALTER will ever finish. Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: @PadraicRenaghan: I added an important aside.

Comment: Thanks again. Very very helpful.

Comment: But note that doing the ALTER TABLE while your session timezone is set to UTC will not cause a table rewrite (it just does that binary coercion thing), while your formulation will cause one.  But if the column is indexed, then that index does need to get rebuilt anyway.

Comment: @jjanes: Thanks for adding, I wasn't aware of this juicy exception. Can make all the difference for the OP! I updated accordingly

Comment: @PadraicRenaghan: Note the update after Jeffs comment.

Comment: Thanks all. The conversion we actually need, somehow. We'd like to get AWS DMS set to timezone ET when loading the data, to get PG to convert on load. But we can't, AWS DMS forces to UTC apparently. Would be great if we could somehow force PG to be in ET when DMS is loading the data. -- let me put this in a new question and see if anyone has ideas...

Comment: other ideas for how to approach this problem [moved to a new question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322946/time-zone-conversion-in-dms-from-db2-to-aurora-postgres)