# Convert PostgreSQL array type

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, array, enum

Given an enum type (e.g. `letter`).

What is the syntax to convert an existing array to the enum type? The existing values are valid for the enum. For example, how would I convert `letter_data` in:

```
create table sample (
 letter_data text[];
);
```

To the `letter` enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert an existing `text[]` array to the enum type `letter[]` (like you ask) simply cast:

```
SELECT '{b,c,a}'::text[]::letter[];
```

To actually convert the table column (like you probably wanted to ask):

```
ALTER TABLE sample ALTER letter_data TYPE letter[] USING letter_data::letter[];
```

Triggers a whole-table rewrite. Only some noted exceptions allow in-place conversion. See:

- [ALTER timestamptz column to timestamp without "converting" data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322904/alter-timestamptz-column-to-timestamp-without-converting-data/322907#322907)

We need the **explicit** cast in a `USING` clause since, quoting [the  manual for `ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

> A `USING` clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_1R_kI_4)

Aside: I rarely use `enum` types. There is often a better solution.