# Why does the now() function return the same value for multiple inserted rows?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Perhaps there's a more idiomatic approach to this in Postgres, but the pattern is reasonably common so I expected it to work.

Here's the code:

```sql
drop table if exists tbl;
create temporary table tbl as select time, NULL as time_ts
from generate_series(1,20000000) as g(time);

drop table if exists timing; 
create table timing(
    info text, 
    n_rows integer, 
    iteration integer,
    time timestamptz);


select now() as before;

DO
$body$
DECLARE
    _value_array integer[] := '{
    100,
    20000,
    5000000
    }
    ';
    t INTEGER;
    iterator integer := 0;
    table_name text := 'test_table';
BEGIN
   FOREACH t IN ARRAY _value_array
   LOOP
      -- add to time table
      insert into timing(info, n_rows, iteration, time) 
      values (format('(%I) before', table_name), t, iterator, now());
      -- Run update
      EXECUTE format(
            'with cte as( '
                'select time '
                'from tbl '
                'where time_ts '
                'is null '
                'limit %s '
            ') '
            'update tbl '
            'set time_ts = cte.time '
            'from cte '
            'where tbl.time = cte.time;', t);
      -- add to time table
      insert into timing(info, n_rows, iteration, time) 
      values (format('(%I) after', table_name), t, iterator, now());
      iterator := iterator + 1;
   END LOOP;
END
$body$;


select now() as after;
```

For which I get the output:

```
            before             
───────────────────────────────
 2023-01-17 01:14:17.056198+00
(1 row)

             after             
───────────────────────────────
 2023-01-17 01:14:44.871277+00
(1 row)
```

And the `timing` table has the content:

```
        info         │ n_rows  │ iteration │             time              
─────────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────────
 (test_table) before │     100 │         0 │ 2023-01-17 01:14:27.756752+00
 (test_table) after  │     100 │         0 │ 2023-01-17 01:14:27.756752+00
 (test_table) before │   20000 │         1 │ 2023-01-17 01:14:27.756752+00
 (test_table) after  │   20000 │         1 │ 2023-01-17 01:14:27.756752+00
 (test_table) before │ 5000000 │         2 │ 2023-01-17 01:14:27.756752+00
 (test_table) after  │ 5000000 │         2 │ 2023-01-17 01:14:27.756752+00
(6 rows)
```

The time within the timing table is at least somewhere between `before` and `after`, but I don't understand why they're all exactly the same time.

**The output that I'm expecting to see** is for each row to have a different time in it, as I would like to know how long each iteration took.

Comment: You might want to try using clock_timestamp() instead

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/63548/3684

Answer (score 3):

The answer, as is sometimes the case, can be found in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> `now()` is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to `transaction_timestamp()`

and

> `transaction_timestamp()` is equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but is named to clearly reflect what it returns

which is, subject to the SQL standard

> the start time of the current transaction

There are other functions that you can use instead:

> PostgreSQL also provides functions that return the start time of the current statement, as well as the actual current time at the instant the function is called [...]
> `statement_timestamp()` returns the start time of the current statement [...] `clock_timestamp()` returns the actual current time, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL command

---

P.S. It is a bad form to use SQL keywords, such as "time", for object names.